# How I can rewrite the code to 1 line without using **do** and **<-**?

Tags: haskell

How I can rewrite the code?

```
foo=do
   str <− readFile "foo" 
   writeFile "bar" str
```

To 1 line without using **do** and **<-**?

Comment: Do you know what `do` and `<-` mean/do?

Comment: `readFile "foo" >>= writeFile "bar"`